# Concat 2 string together in rego

Tags: string, function, concatenation, opa, rego

How can I concat 2 strings?

Here, I tried to define a function that concats "f" to the end of a provided string:

```
concat_f(bar) = output{
    item := ["f"]
    x := concat(bar, item)
    output := x
}
```

But when I try to use it (passing in `bar` as `"123"`):

```
hello {
    x := input.bar
    y := concat_f(x)
    y == "123f"
}
```

I get that `hello` is equals to `false`

Why is that? And how do I concat strings properly?

[Here are the docs on the topic. Found nothing useful](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/)

Answer (score 2):

because its checking the condition y == "123f" and reports false.

Your item is array and input is string. I usually convert to an array or set to do the concat, string I find it difficult, may be Im new aswell

https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/sETVNU37B8

```
package play

concat_f(bar) = output{
    item := ["fine"]
    out := array.concat(bar, item)
    x := concat("", out)
    output := x
}

hello = y {
    x := input.bar
    y := concat_f(x)
    #y == "123fine"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`concat`](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#builtin-strings-concat) to suffix the given input *bar* with `"f"` using an empty-string as delimiter.

Here defined as simple function:

```
concat_f(bar) = concat("", [bar, "f"])
```

Then `concat_f("123")` will return `"123f"`.